# What does the \newline escape sequence mean in python?

Tags: python, escaping, newline, string-literals

I found the sequence `\newline` in a [list of escape sequences in the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=literals#index-18). I wonder how it is used and for what. At least in my interpreter it seems this is just interpreted as `'\n' + 'ewline'`:

```
>>> print('\newline')

ewline
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It refers to the actual newline character - the one with character code "10" (0x0a) - not the text sequence "newline".

So, an example is like:

```
print("a\
b")
```

Here, the backslash is succeeded by the newline, inside a string, and what is printed is just "ab" with nothing apart.

it differs from `\n` - in here, the characer following the backslash is `n` (0x6e), and this sequence is translated to `\x0a` on parsing the string. On `\<newline>`, the source string contains the `\x0a` character and that is replaced by an empty string.

Maybe the documentation on that page would be more clear if it would read `\<newline>` instead of just `\newline`.

Comment: There's a separate entry `'\n'` which exactly refers to what you're saying. So the question is, what prompted another entry `'\newline'` and why.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: No, that entry refers to a backslash and an `n`. This is a backslash and a newline.

Comment: @user2357112 Oh, cool, that makes sense. So it's talking about the line continuation character, not the `\n` newline.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you are alluding to is explaining how a backslash followed by a literal newline is ignored, as if the next line were physically joined with the line on which the starting backslash was found.

The string `\newline'` has no special meaning; it is exactly what you say you think it is.